# Is it possible to pass network errors to client

Tags: node.js

I have created a http server which is creating proxy to send requests to target system.

```
function sendErrorResponse(client_req,client_res){
    var options = {
        :
    };

    var proxy = http.request(options, function (res) {
        res.pipe(client_res, {
            end: true
        });
    });

    client_req.pipe(proxy, {
        end: true
    });
}
```

or using http-proxy npm package

```
function sendErrorResponse(client_req,client_res){
    proxy.web(client_req, client_res, { target: 'http://localhost:7777' });
}
```

Now when client request to my server, I proxy some of the requests to other server and send to client whtever I get from the target server. I want that if target server gives some error (DNS resolution, network errors etc.) I can send same to the client instead of responding client with `500` with some error message.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why don't you use errors callback, and format the response as you want?. `proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://mytarget.com:8080' }, function(error) { //Here format the response with the error message })`

Comment: I tried but it din't work, can you plz give me an example how to write the same error to the client request?